# No Complete Sentences, Colons?

Tags: terminology, colons

> Almost every summer he thinks: This is the best summer. But this summer, he knows, really is the best. **And not just the summer: the spring, the winter, the fall.** As he gets older, he is given, increasingly, to thinking of his life as a series of retrospectives, assessing each season as it passes as if it’s a vintage of wine, dividing years he’s just lived into historical eras: The Ambitious Years. The Insecure Years. The Glory Years. The Delusional Years. The Hopeful Years.
>
> — Hanya Yanagihara, *A Little Life*

I’ve read that you don’t have to, grammatically, write a complete sentence, and then write a colon.

In *And not just the summer: the spring, the winter, the fall.*, I don’t see a complete sentence, then a colon, and I don’t see a complete sentence used after the colon. There may not seem any utterances, which I think I’ve read may get used.

What may you call this, in grammar?

Comment: This doesn't address your actual question, but I cannot think of any time when it is necessary to have commas before _and_ after the word "and" or the word "then."  There may be some, but they escape me.

Comment: I agree with Adam (although I can think of times you'd use a comma before and after "then" and "and" this is not one of them). I think about 5 of your 13 commas are unnecessary, and add some confusion to your question.

Comment: We call this **writing**. Writers are not restricted by the rules of grammar school. Thank goodness. We write and say *thoughts*, and they are not always the *"complete sentences"* learnt in school.

Answer (score 2):

Each side of the colon is a **sentence fragment**. To properly get at the meaning, it should be combined with the preceding sentence.

> This summer, he knows, really is the best, and not just the summer: the spring, the winter, and the fall.

A complete sentence, ending in a colon, and followed by a fragment is correct usage.

Yanagihara's writing is not a good example of accepted grammar, because she is using **her own style** to **create an effect**. Her intention is to resemble **how a person thinks**, which is typically in short, recursive fragments rather than complete and complex sentences. Many of her sentences begin with conjunctions in order to make it sound like a continuous chain of thought. This isn't always possible to achieve when you **follow the rules**. The sentence may be conventionally "wrong", but its meaning is clear. Part of the effect of grammar is the ability to misuse it.

Answer (score 0):

What do I call this, grammatically-speaking?   I call it wrong.  The English grammar rule has always been that a complete sentence is needed before a colon. The author may have been trying to do something stylistically in this writing.  However, looking only through the eyes of English grammar, I'm afraid I must call it incorrect.